# How To Bulk Import wp_postmeta records in an API call?

Tags: rest-api, bulk-import

I need to sync a Rails database with a WordPress db, using API calls. Each Rails record creates one `wp_post`, and up to 15 `wp_postmeta` records. I can loop over the data that becomes the postmetas, but that takes a long time. I assume most of that time comes from making so many API calls, so I'm trying to cut that number down to one.

For a single record, I've cobbled this URL together, which works:

```
https://mysite.wpengine.com/wp-json/imports/v1/new_postmeta/?post_id=202559&meta_key=activity_id&meta_value=2387511
```

I tried putting the following into my `functions.php` file to create a custom route:

```php
function bulk_import_postmeta($request) {
    $metas = $request->get_param("meta");
  if (is_array($metas)) {
    foreach($metas as $meta){
      update_post_meta($meta[0], $meta[1], $meta[2]);
    }
  }
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('/imports/v1', '/postmeta_bulk/',
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'bulk_import_postmeta',
            'args' => array('meta' => array('required' => true))));
});
```

—but I don't know how I need to encode the URL when I call it, and I don't know if it would work if I did.

My question is, then: given a `post_id`, what API call can I make to bulk create these `wp_postmeta` records?

Comment: Can you dump to csv and use eg wp-cli?

Comment: @birgire, the process needs to be automatic and cron-tabbable.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the existing `meta` property (see [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#schema-meta)) to add multiple meta fields (in a JSON format) when we create a post via POST method:

```
POST: example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/

Body payload:

{
    "title": "My title",
    "content": "My content",
    "meta": {"myfield1":"myvalue1", "myfield2":"myvalue2"}
}
```

or when we want to update a post with ID 123:

```
POST: example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/123

Body payload:

{
    "title": "My title 2",
    "content": "My content 2",
    "meta": {"myfield1":"myvalue11", "myfield2":"myvalue22"}
}
```

Note that we will have to register the meta fields with corresponding schema properties (see [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/) and [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/)), for example registering meta field `myfield1` as a string with:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_post_meta(
         'post', // post type
         'myfield1', // meta key
         array(
             'single'       => true,
             'type'         => 'string',
             'show_in_rest' => array(
                 'schema' => array(
                     'type'    => 'string',
                     'default' => '',
                 ),
             ),
         )
     );
} );
```

We can see how the `meta` scheme property is checked in the *rest posts controller*:

```
if ( ! empty( $schema['properties']['meta'] ) && isset( $request['meta'] ) ) {
    $meta_update = $this->meta->update_value( $request['meta'], $post_id );

    if ( is_wp_error( $meta_update ) ) {
        return $meta_update;
    }
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/create_item/