# Cant create or update meta fields using WordPress REST API

Tags: post-meta, rest-api, wp-api

I have wp theme with custom fields in posts with following meta keys in photo, can't create post with custom fields values using rest-api (I'm able to create posts with no problem but cant edit or add meta values). (I'm not a ninja in wp or php) [image]

Comment: Maybe my recent answer here can help https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/408083/26350

Comment: How are you attempting to perform the update/insertion? What is the server's response?

Comment: @birgire should I add specific code line to be able to update the meta value?

Comment: @bosco Just normal update with PUT to my post id using postman and When I try to update post title and any meta value, I got the updated title but no changes in meta value

Comment: @Rafal yes as explained in the linked answer